# I'm trying to define a function that can update a given list every time it's called ..I want this function to add dictionaries to the list as items

Tags: list, function, loops, dictionary

I want the function to append dictionaries to a list but it's appending the keys of the dictionaries only. Whereas I wanted to append the dictionary as a whole

here's my code

def add_gamer (gamer, gamers_list):

```
if 'name' in gamer and 'availability' in gamer:
    gamers_list += {'name': gamer['name'], 'availability': gamer['availability']}
return gamers_list
```

gamers = []
kimberly = {'name': 'Kimberley', 'availability': ['Mondays', 'Tuesady', 'Fridays']}

print ( add_gamer (kimberly, gamers) )

Here's the output I'm getting :

['name', 'availability']

I was expecting the output to be :

[{'name': 'Kimberley', 'availability': ['Mondays', 'Tuesady', 'Fridays']}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 'append' not '+='

```
gamers_list.append({'name': gamer['name'], 'availability': gamer['availability']})
```

'append' appends an object, '+=' appends a literal value